# Horizion.io collection with public read access not working

Tags: rethinkdb, horizon

I am trying to access a non-authenticated collection on my local Horizion server.

Here is my schema.toml

```
[collections.developerProfiles]

[collections.users]

[groups.default.rules.read_public_profile]
template = "collection('developerProfiles').find({id: any()})"

[groups.authenticated.rules.store_message]
template = "collection('developerProfiles').store({id: any(), comments: any(), score: any()})"

[groups.default.rules.read_current_user]
template = "collection('users').find({id: userId()})"
```

Here is how I am making the request.

```
const ProfileCollection = _horizon('developerProfiles');

    ProfileCollection.find({
        id: 'someId'
    }).fetch().subscribe(collection => {
        console.log('collection', collection);
    })
```

Here is the error via the socket: Unhandled error: Error: Unauthenticated connections are not allowed.

My question: why does a find only work when I am authenticated? When I defined a default rule? What am I missing here.

Comment: Hey Carlos, just running a few tests. Just making sure you're getting the "Operation not permitted" output in your dev console when you try to run `ProfileCollection.find` as an unauthenticated and not something else?

Comment: I get this error: auth.js:171Uncaught Error: Attempting to authenticate with a token, but no token is present   which is weird because the resource I am requesting should be public.

Comment: If it helps I am using react with @horizon/client I've seem to have tried every permission in the documentation.

Comment: What does you horizon object instantiation look like? I.e. `const horizon = ....`

Comment: I've used both: Horizion() and Horizon({
 authType: 'token'
}). My configuration is very close to the one found here: http://tutorials.pluralsight.com/interesting-apis/building-a-real-time-application-with-react-react-router-horizon-io-and-oauth

Comment: Everything works if I authenticated, I just cant seem to create a public resource

Comment: Here is the error via the socket: Unhandled error: Error: Unauthenticated connections are not allowed.

Comment: I guess a good place for me is "how can I create a public resource with a private resource" with Horizon

Comment: Using: const _horizon = Horizon({
 authType: 'unauthenticated'
}); also doesn't work I get this error: Unhandled error: Error: Unauthenticated connections are not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out!

If you want a collection to be available to unathenticated users you must do the following.

1) Your connection to Horizon

```
const _horizon = Horizon({
   authType: 'unauthenticated'
});
```

2 ) Permissions

```
[groups.default.rules.read_public_profile]
template = "collection('developerProfiles').find({id: any()})"
```

3 ) Auth Settings ( what I was missing )

```
allow_unauthenticated: true
```

Comment: I just came here to say this after seeing your comments :D, you basically need two code paths, one to if a user has a token because they have authenticated (using `horizon.hasAuthToken()`) and the second if they are not-yet-authenticated (`horizon.hasAuthToken()` will return false). For the latter, you'll use `authType: 'unauthenticated'` as you've shown here.